# Spring MongoDB driver not supporting hierarchical structure of Java domain objects

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

When trying to design java domain objects for mongodb collection in a hierarchical structure, its throwing an exception. As per JSON representation, this should be allowed, but, here its not supported. Anybody know the reason? is it a bug in spring mongo driver?

```
@Document
public class SomeReason{
  private SomeReason reason;
  private List<String> options;
  // getter & setter
}
```

Exception Stacktrace here.,

```
00:38:22,017  INFO MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver:259 - Found cycle for field 'reason' in type 'SomeReason' for path ''
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$CyclicPropertyReferenceException: Found cycle for field 'reason' in type 'SomeReason' for path ''
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$CycleGuard.protect(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:473)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:231)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:226)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:309)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.appendTextIndexInformation(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:226)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.access$400(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:256)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:226)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:309)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.appendTextIndexInformation(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:226)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.access$400(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:256)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:226)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:309)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.appendTextIndexInformation(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:226)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.potentiallyCreateTextIndexDefinition(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:205)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.resolveIndexForEntity(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:99)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.resolveIndexForClass(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.resolveIndexForClass(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForAndCreateIndexes(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:128)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForIndexes(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.onApplicationEvent(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.onApplicationEvent(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:46)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:306)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:180)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.determineCollectionName(MongoTemplate.java:1943)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.determineEntityCollectionName(MongoTemplate.java:1930)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:730)
```

Comment: Hierarchical structure is supported. What's the exception you're getting?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code and the entity should be mapped as expected in MongoDB. The exception you get is logged as `INFO`.